# PHP PDF causing Microsoft Visual C++ runtime error in IE

Tags: php, visual-c++, pdf, runtime-error

I have a site that builds some pdfs and serves them to the browser by saving them to the server then redirecting the browser to the file.

When you try and access these pdfs in Internet Explorer the browser crashes displaying a:

Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library

Program: iexplorer.exe

This application has requested a Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

The pdfs are built using fpdf I have included the serve part of the function below

```
//set encryption
    $pdf->setEncryption('',$pdfPassword,array('print'));

    #create the pdf and stream it to the page
    $pdfcode = $pdf->ezOutput(1);
    //$pdfcode = str_replace("\n","\n",htmlspecialchars($pdfcode));
    $filename = $info['Certificate_Number'].time().".pdf";
    $finalPdf = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/downloads/certificates/".$filename;
    $pdfFile = fopen($finalPdf, 'w');
    fwrite($pdfFile, $pdfcode);
    header('location: /downloads/certificates/'.$filename);
```

Comment: If that only happens with the PDFs you generate, not with neutral others, it might be a good idea to supply one sample for inspection.

Comment: I'm waiting to hear if it happens with others but from a quick google it seems a relatively common issue for IE users and pdfs. Unfortunately the pdfs contain discrete data so I cannot release an actual file.

Comment: Is this working on any other browser? Have you tried opening the resulting files locally with acrobat reader to make sure you are not generating corrupt PDF files? Without a sample file, this is all the advice I can give you.

Comment: yeah, it works in literally everything else on other operating systems, even windows xp IE7. I've also oopened the files generated when accessing the site from IE9 on a different computer and they work fine.